# Google Location Api V3 is not returning location id node but its available on v2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

a location id node  is present in location Google Location API V2 using following Url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=london,%20Canada&types=geocode&sensor=true&key=my_key

which ultimately returns result and a part of it is shown below:

```
<prediction>
<description>London, ON, Canada</description>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
<type>geocode</type>
<reference>
CjQqAAAAbN8JV6qwIOKVmGuRGXNc53ihbUG9GlHkRhwUh8ABdUgGC1IbdTRGVIdq5GtkATC_EhAKYnqcPv4ouW5QG5mG1AlOGhSa9oE0Cts801iMReUGyqG7mWZlfw
</reference>
<id>fab6815aadba41e81aa7bd51a445c4924317ec88</id>
```

but when i use the newer version of google location Api v3 using following url:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=london+canada

it does not includes `<id>`, Please Help needed

Answer (score 0):

The first link in your question requests the **[placesWebService](https://developers.google.com/places/)**, but the second requests the the **[geocodingWebService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding)**.

You can still use the first link, **V3** is the current Version of the Maps-**Javascript**-API, but you don't use the Javascript-API, you request a webservice(changes to the Maps-Javascript-API don't have any effect to the webservices).

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but sir the problem is: placesWebService return abbreviation of states in Canada & USA but i need complete state name which is available in geocodingWebService. And the other problem is id, as i am using placesWebService earlier and i am tracking ids

Comment: Request the [place-details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) to get the complete state-names